# The '__proto__' property is deprecated with standard js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, standardjs

How to change the `this.constructor.prototype.__proto__ = Error.prototype` as per the standard js rules. Standard Js is throwing `The '__proto__' property is deprecated`. So what will be correct solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve (Prototypal) Inheritance, you can link the two objects as follows:

```
this.constructor.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype)
```

Although many browsers have supported the usage of `__proto__` as means of accessing the internal `[[Prototype]]` of an object, it has only been standardised in ES6 and its usage is still frowned upon.

Similar effect can be achieved by using  ES6's `Object.setPrototypeOf(..)`.

Consult [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) for more information.

Hope this helps!